# Keras neural network input shapes

Tags: deep-learning, word-embeddings

In [this example from the Keras repository](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py), this convolutional neural network is trained:

```
>>> model.summary()
------------------------------------------
Initial input shape: (None, 5000)  -------
------------------------------------------
Layer (name)                  Output Shape                  Param #             
------------------------------------------
Embedding (embedding)         (None, 100, 100)              500000              
Dropout (dropout)             (None, 100, 100)              0                   
Convolution1D (convolution1d) (None, 98, 250)               75250               
MaxPooling1D (maxpooling1d)   (None, 49, 250)               0                   
Flatten (flatten)             (None, 12250)                 0                   
Dense (dense)                 (None, 250)                   3062750             
Dropout (dropout)             (None, 250)                   0                   
Activation (activation)       (None, 250)                   0                   
Dense (dense)                 (None, 1)                     251                 
Activation (activation)       (None, 1)                     0                   
------------------------------------------
Total params: 3638251
------------------------------------------
```

The `imdb` dataset contains reviews, each composed of different words. So given a 5000-word vocabulary, according to the `Initial input shape` the first embedding layer should get a vector of 5000 counters for each review. Each counter `i` saying how many times the `i`-th word appears, I suppose.
However when I dump any set's input shape, I get:

```
>>> X_train.shape
(20000, 100)
```

Where 20000 is the number of the reviews (let's ignore it here), and 100 is the number of words. From there the embedding layer maps it to

```
(None, 100, 100)
```

as seen in the column `Output shape`. The first 100 is the number of words in the review, and the second 100 is a mapping of each word to a 100-dimension space.

I cannot understand the discrepancy between `Initial input shape` and `X.shape` where `X` is a training or test set. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

From what I think, your X datasets are 20K sequences of 100 "words" each, where each word is a string. Embedding layer is 1st converting it to one-hot  i.e. Initial input shape and then to the embedding dimension.

Comment: The words could be a string or some integer representing some string